# how to access members of another modules in python

Tags: python, module

```
Demo1.py
--------
   ph=10
   def ph():
        print("Phone")
   def email():
        print("Email")
```

---

```
Demo2.py
---------
from Demo1 import ph,email
      print(email)
      print(ph)

output: Email 
    <function ph at 0x0000021E81BC3158>
```

When I print variable `ph` in **demo2.py** module it will call function but not variable `ph`. How do I access the variable `ph`?

Comment: Why define a variable and a function with the same name at the first place?

Comment: i am a beginner in python, i don't have any special requirement. but if i have a case like that then how to access variable ph,

Comment: You can't - as the answers below. You need to modify your function/var name

Answer (score 4):

Your variable and function have the same in Demo1.py, *ph*. Since the function is defined later in the script, *ph* references the function. Change the name of either and that should solve the problem:

```
# Demo1.py
ph = 10
def phone():
    print("Phone")
def email():
    print("Email")
```

Also, since you already print inside the functions in *Demo1.py*, you don't need to print them again in *Demo2.py*, but you would need to print the value of variable *ph*:

```
# Demo2.py
from Demo1 import ph, phone, email
print(ph)
email
phone
```

Output:

```
10
Phone
Email
```

Comment: if i change variable name or function name, then i can access, but my interest is without changing variable name or function name how to access variable ph in other module.

Answer (score 1):

`ph`'s definition is overwritten by the function declaration.

To access the variable, simply rename any one of the `ph`s.